# Storing infrequently used data sets in S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I want a solution to store data that is not often accessed. For example, analytical data that I may not need to frequently access and instead only refer to counter columns stored in records in a local postgres database.

I’ve looked at Amazon [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) and [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) but I think [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) might be the best solution (for now). I like DynamoDB, but I think its overkill for what I need. I’ve also looked into the [Amazon Big Data solutions](http://aws.amazon.com/big-data/), which I feel is almost definitely overkill. I’ve heard of companies using S3 to store infrequently accessed data sets (rather than the traditional use of media).

What should I use? Is S3 a horribly bad idea? If S3 is a good idea, how would I use it to store data sets? I’ve used S3, [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and [fog](https://github.com/fog/fog) a lot for storing media, but not for data.

#### Example data

I want to store all the [responses from emails that are sent by Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html). This will eventually accumulate a lot of data and I may not use the data for a long time, but I want to store it regardless.

I’m thinking about combining the emails into a set and grouping them by day. And I can store the counters (which I will access frequently) in a single record in my local postgres database (one record per day). I won’t be able to search through the raw email data without *loading the day*, but I don’t think I need to.

Comment: Rather than storing everything in dynamo, you can store references to S3 buckets / paths as the records in dynamo. This will give you the storage cost savings by using S3 instead of dynamo.

Comment: Very interesting, I hadn't previously considered this. Thanks!